# List of digraphs in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, list, matlab, list-comprehension, digraphs

I am a beginner in MATLAB.

I have a function that takes an integer as input and returns a directed graph ([`digraph`](https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/digraph.html)); I therefore have a list of integers `L`, and would like to create a list of digraphs derived from such integers.

I have a function `create_graph(n)` that returns such digraph.

What I am currently doing is:

```
Gs = [];
for i=1:length(L)
   x = L(i);
   G = create_graph(x);
   Gs(end + 1) = G;
end
```

And it returns an error:

```
Unable to perform assignment because value of type 'digraph' is not convertible to 'double'.

Error in dummy_code (line 20)
    Gs(end + 1) = G;

Caused by:
    Error using double
    Conversion to double from digraph is not possible.
```

Another error appear if I initialize a dummy digraph, that is:

```
Gs = [digraph([1,1;1,1])];
for i=1:length(L)
   x = L(i);
   G = create_graph(x);
   Gs(end + 1) = G;
end
```

```
Error using indexing
Unsupported graph indexing.
```

What I would like to do is something close to the `python` code:

```
Gs = [create_graph(x) for x in L]
```

Comment: set `Gs = {}; ...; Gs(end + 1) = {G};` to make `Gs` a cell array of digraphs.

Comment: Each item in a Python list can be any type of Python object. Each item in a MATLAB matrix or vector must be a numeric value. The nearest MATLAB equivalent to a Python list is a cell array.